# 2005 Dodge Durango radio replacement. Wiring problem

Tags: audio, dodge, durango

I have a 2005 Dodge Durango. I'm switching out my radio and found that I have 3 wires with constant power, 2 are grey with red strip and the other is solid white.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking why there are 3 that provide constant power, or what they are for, or do you have a problem with the radio staying on?